# Web Api error messages localization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In .NET WebApi I have a class for request model.
Required Attributes works fine. Its returned custom error messages.
But the type of conversion errors return default error message.

How can I change this messages?

[image]

```
public class MyTest
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ApiMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Glb_Required")]
    public int? Code { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ApiMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Glb_Required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ApiMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Glb_StringLength")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ApiMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Glb_Required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ApiMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Glb_StringLength")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of NuGet packages with resources for different languages and technologies. If you're lucky enough,your desired language will be available. If not, you'll have to take one of the satellite assemblies of other language and transtalte it to yours. For example:

- [Recursos de español para Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.es/)
- [Deutsche Ressourcen für Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.de/)
- [Risorse in lingua italiana per Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.it/)
- [Ressources du français pour Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.fr/)

I've shown the resources for EF because this are the resources that include the validation messages related to Data Annotations EF Validation (I think those are the erros you're showing). If your messages doesn't come from EF validation, there are also packages of Resources for ASP.NET MVC, and for many other Microsoft technologies. Just lokk for "Resources for My Language for ASP.NET MVC", for exaple "Recursos para español para ASP.NET MVC", if your language is Spanish, in NuGet.

**NOTE: remember to change the culture configuration of your web site, so that the chosen language is used. If not it will have no effect**

If you have to translate one of these assemblies, simply rename it with the extension of your culture, and open it with visual studio, which will allow you to edit it.